# Merge terminal command with LaTeX

Tags: bash, latex, texlive, merge

I am using following command to generate a non-copyable pdf

```
gs -o output.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite input.pdf
```

The file `input.pdf` is created using `LaTeX`.

Is it possible to merge the command with LaTeX such that everytime I run/execute LaTeX it will give me non-copyable file `output.pdf` instead of `input.pdf`

Comment: How are you running latex?

Comment: I have `TexLive` installed and I am compiling using `TexStudio`

Comment: In that case, probably you should edit [the build commands](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02)